# Starting a GUI application under a different session

Tags: rdp, windows, startup, session

I run a game hosting service, and I want my customers to be able to access the console of the game servers. However, despite looking like a terminal window, the game's server console is graphical, and I cannot capture the standard output or input from it. I have thought of another solution: creating a Windows user account for each game server. Then, from the "Administrator" session, I want to launch the game server under that Windows user.

I want the console window to be viewable when the user connects via RDP. The entire purpose of this solution is so the customers can view the console input/output by connecting to their session with RDP. I've tried using multiple combinations of the `runas` and `start` commands, but when I try to test those combinations by attempting to launch Notepad, it doesn't work. Either nothing gets started, or it runs under the Administrator session.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the web based remote desktop and instead of launching into a session, use it to launch the app instead within the RDP session.  If you do this, then there is no setup on the user side.  If you use MSTSC, then you can still do the same thing, but the users have to add the app to launch.  You can lock down the username they login with so they are very limited on what they can do, but they will have to launch the app themselves from the RDP desktop.  We do this with my end users who use their thin clients for data collection.  They are locked out of everything except IE and the logoff commands.  Works great, but there could be holes if you miss something in security.